# Play random sound on button that is spammable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem that i want to have a button, that plays random sound after I press it, but the other thing is that i want to spam the button and so does the sound. What I mean is that i dont want to wait for the sound to finish to play it again and like have 5 sounds or more playing depending on your click speed.

```js
for(var i=0;i<1;i++)
{
  document.getElementById("MyAudio.mp3")[i].addEventListener("click",function(){});
}

function playAudio()
{
    var audio = new Audio("MyAudio.mp3");
    audio.play();
}
```

```html
<button onlick="playAudio()"></button>
```

Comment: Typo: `onlick` should be `onclick`

Comment: @Barmar Maybe it's a new event for tongue-sensitive devices? 

Comment: @IMSoP All I can say is "Ewwww!'

Comment: You have some very odd things in this code. The for loop count from 0 to 0; and [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns a single element, so getting the 0th item in it won't do anything useful. And then you bind (or attempt to bind) the event to a button with no id anyway, using an old-style HTML event attribute.

Comment: that all cool but can you atleast help me to fix it instead of complaining because im not too good at this

Answer (score 0):

That sounds fun and there's many ways to do it. I think the easiest way would be to pre-load the songs ahead of time and randomize it.

```js
// Your sounds
let sounds = [new Audio('https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-3s.mp3'), new Audio('https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-6s.mp3'), new Audio('https://www.soundjay.com/human/fart-01.mp3')];
let lastSound = 0; // Not necessary but we don't want overlapping tracks.
// Listen for click on button (ID soundmachine)
// pointerdown is more suitable so adjusted it.
document.querySelector("#soundmachine1").addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
// This is a small fix to allow the sound to be spammable and clear last track.
  sounds[lastSound].pause();
  sounds[lastSound].currentTime = 0;
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
  sounds[random].play();
  lastSound = random; // For the next click we want to cancel this sound if it's playing.
  console.log(lastSound); // Just so you can see it count/play
});
document.querySelector("#soundmachine2").addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
  // Play till completed
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * sounds.length);
  sounds[random].play();
});
```

```html
<button id="soundmachine1">click me ver1</div>
<button id="soundmachine2">click me ver2</div>
```

Something like this!

Comment: Comments have been added to help you understand. I randomly select track, stop previously playing tracks and allow for it to be spammable, give it a go! :)

Comment: Thats what ive been looking for, but theres one thing, when i click it again the sound that has been playing stops and plays the 2nd one instead. what i want that there has to be playing sound on sound, i hope you know what i mean.

Comment: So you want sound1 to trigger and if I click again sound2 or 3 may trigger and all play at the same time? So what happens if sound1 gets triggered while it's playing do nothing? Should all sounds playing restart or continue till finish.

Comment: I mean i want to click on the button to play the sound but dont want to cancel it when i press the button again. so when I span the button there will be the like mashup of the random played sounds.

Comment: Check version 2; few removals of code and you're off to the races. You can remove the other event listener/lastSound and the element. GL!

Comment: Thats more like it but there seems to be some sort of delay but thanks a lot!!

Comment: Delay would be the samples downloading first load wait a few. If you like this answer, do feel free to select it. :)

Comment: @BGPHiJACK - great answer - Would there be a way of doing this without pre-loading every single audio file? I've had a go but can't quite get it!

Answer (score -1):

There's some odd things going on with this code, so let's rethink it from the beginning. First of all, you want to create an onclick handler on your button that plays your mp3 file. Let's do that first:

```
let audio = new Audio("MyAudio.mp3");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  audio.play()
});
```

Now, it sounds like you want it to play from the beginning every time when clicked, and not wait till it completes (which is the default behavior). So we need to reset the playback every time you click.

```
let audio = new Audio("MyAudio.mp3");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();
});
```

And your HTML can just look like this:

```
<button>Play</button>
```